# Counting up array results from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i've got a problem with my php script. I want to check my script if there is anything in array and if there's no to echo a message but when array is empty it just don't echo nothing.

That's my code:

```
    include("mysql_connect.php");
$name = $_POST['playerName'];
$users = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM playerdata WHERE username LIKE "'.$name.'%"');
        if($name==""){
        echo 'Type in player name!';
    }else{
while($usersList= mysql_fetch_assoc($users)){
    if(!array_count_values($usersList)){
        echo 'Player not found';
    }else{
        echo $usersList['username'].', ';
    }
}//While end.
}//If name is empty end.
```

Comment: `WHERE username LIKE "'.$name.'%"');` is missing a `'` before the variable

Comment: No it doesn't because i'm using " not ' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you have to check for rows before the loop.

```
$rows = mysql_num_rows($users);
if($rows==0) echo "No rows..";
else {
  foreach() {
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems is that, if a user enters a `invalid` name, the `while loop` does not execute, as the query simply cannot find any rows, the `code` should be as follows

```
include("mysql_connect.php");
$name = $_POST['playerName'];

if( $name === "" ){
    echo 'Type in player name!';
} else {
    $users = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM playerdata WHERE username LIKE "'.$name.'%"');

    if ( mysql_num_rows($users) == 0) {
        echo "Invalid Player name provided";
    } else {
        while($usersList= mysql_fetch_assoc($users)){
        {
            echo $usersList['username'].', ';
        } //While end.
    }
}//empty name
```

**Notes:**

1. I have `re-formatted` the code as it looked ugly
2. The query is executed only if a user provides some text for name, why `execute` the query when the name is `empty` !

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
if(!array_count_values($usersList)){
```

use

```
if(empty($usersList)){
```

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop wont be executed if $users is empty, so the condition:

```
if(!array_count_values($usersList)){
        echo 'Player not found';
   }
```

will never be met because it is contained in a loop which will never run.

Comment: No because $name is seperate value

Comment: Try adding: echo 'here'; above  if(!array_count_values($usersList)){ and see if the loop is being executed

Comment: It begins but when it's empty it doesn't do anything

Comment: so does it echo 'here' when you use a name that isnt in the database?

Comment: No it doesn't do anything. :/

Comment: No because my code runs when $name value equals something and it doesn't matter because when for example I type in "asdadasfasdf" then it runs the loop because $name equals something and then inside the loop i want to check if array equals something but it doesn't work inside the loop :/ I'm so confused now.